# Best Server (Linux/Windows) Software for Backups While Server is handling content

Tags: linux, backup, virtual-machines

We're using ARECA (http://www.areca-backup.org/) for backups of our Windows & Linux Servers. The biggest problem we have experienced is that once backup starts on one of our Linux Virtual Machine (acting as LAMP Server) = the sites on that VM basically stop to respond, as ARECA it seems consume most of available resources and our LAMP sites stops to work properly.

We don't use "ZIPPing" option on Areca, so we just send files over network (with Areca). Any ideas what we should tune here?

Or maybe you can recommend a different (better) solution, as when we have Areca started our CPU% consumptions jumps to 30% immediately.

Thank you for your help

thanks,
Dmitry

Comment: what type of hypervisor are you running?

Comment: VMWare ESXi 4.1

Answer (score 2):

What type of virtual machines are they? If they are VMware, you should look into something that takes advantage of the VStorage APIs

Comment: 3 machines are dedicated physical servers (not virtualized) and I have 2 beefy servers for virtualized environment running vmware on both - each contains VMs that should be backuped

Answer (score 1):

We have used Doubletake for low overhead server migration and backup.

http://www.visionsolutions.com/

It monitors system resources to not tax your active server while backing up files